# Tinymapper and Autmapper fail to map objects of the type dynamic proxy classes from entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, automapper, dynamic-proxy, tinymapper

I am having ASP.Net Entities with their repositories and Viewmodels to get exposed from my Services layer. When I try to Bind any of my entity to viewmodel, I am getting an exception saying that the mapping is impossible between these two objects (though the objects have same set of properties).

I could somehow get an idea that this is due to the entity framework returns dynamic proxy objects from the lazy loading. These classes are neither handled in Tinymapper nor the Automapper object mapping libraries.

I believe, disabling dynamic proxy creation is not recommended as they have change tracking information which is required for making use of the advantages of entity framework.

Is there any solution for this problem? please let me know. thanks in advance.